# Not able to add gms and FCM dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to android. I'm building an App that requires Map as well as FCM. So to customize markers and set latitude and langitude I'm using gms.

This is my app level gradle build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'                   
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the below is my project level gradle build file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
 }
}
```

So when I include both the following dependencies in app level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

I'm getting the following error while running the application.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 20.671 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

But when I remove the firebase-messaging dependency it's working. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: use same version for both dependencies 9.2.0

Comment: Thanks @DivyeshPatel for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle use same version of `Gms` and `firebase` dependencies.

And as you are only using Google map , no need to import the whole library, use only the map selective portion.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1
```

in your code:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1                  
}
```

Comment: Will try and let you know. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @Praveenupadrasta you are welcome...mark the answer as correct if it helps, ..thankx